# Data miss in socket transfer

Tags: python, sockets

I want to build a server socket and send a line to an client and the client will print the line

but when I print the data received from server socket , only the first line of the file be print , others are miss

I notice that sometimes the data will still have data after the "\n" so I add the following two lines of code , it will shows error "substring not found"
but sometimes the client will receive this kind of data "5000\n1000" so the client need to keep the 1000 ...

```
remain = data[data.index("\n")+1:]
data = remain
```

this is the data I want to send to client

```
1000 2000 3000 4000 5000
1000 3000 5000 7000 9000
1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
```

server

```
import socket

Input = open("./Data","r")
data = Input.read()
Input.close()

# Construct the server_socket
server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.bind(('localhost',15000))
server_sock.listen(1)
(client_socket,address) = server_sock.accept()

# send data
for line in data:
    client_socket.send(line)

client_socket.send("EOF")
client_socket.close()
server_sock.close()
```

client

```
import socket

client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(('localhost',15000))

data = ""
while True:
    part = client_sock.recv(100)
    data = data + part
    if "\n" in data or "EOF" in data:
        list = data[:data.index("\n")].split(" ")
        print(list)
        remain = data[data.index("\n")+1:]
        data = remain
        if "EOF" in data:
            break

client_sock.close()
result.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want is:

```
Input.readLines()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to indent

```
client_socket.send(line)
```

Comment: oh ok, I assume that means you actually had it indented in your code.  Other than that, maybe line doesn't contain a return?

Comment: what does it mean "line contain a return?"

Comment: meaning your variable "line" which you are sending, does it contain a "\n"?  I don't think it would.

Comment: but the source file have "\n" in the end of the line , if I directly read it will keep the "\n"

Comment: oh sorry I thought you were using Input.readLines() not Input.read()